# Windows Server 2012 Updates not available

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I've run AWS Inspector on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server and it detected some vulnerabilities. For example, this one [CVE-2019-11091](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-11091), which is fixed in [KB4499158](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4499158/windows-server-2012-update-kb4499158).

However, this are the update I have installed:

[image: installed updates]

That means that all updates are installed (except 3 that came in the last week).

Is that issue supposed to be fixed or not? I'm trying to understand if I need to fix it another way, it hasn't been fixed yet or AWS inspector is not working well. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Greg's suggested script output:

**Speculation control settings for CVE-2017-5715 [branch target injection]**

> Hardware support for branch target injection mitigation is present: False
>
> Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is present: True
>
> Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is enabled: False
>
> Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is disabled by system policy: True
>
> Windows OS support for branch target injection mitigation is disabled by absence of hardware support: True

**Speculation control settings for CVE-2017-5754 [rogue data cache load]**

> Hardware requires kernel VA shadowing: True
>
> Windows OS support for kernel VA shadow is present: True
>
> Windows OS support for kernel VA shadow is enabled: False

**Speculation control settings for CVE-2018-3639 [speculative store bypass]**

> Hardware is vulnerable to speculative store bypass: True
>
> Hardware support for speculative store bypass disable is present: False
>
> Windows OS support for speculative store bypass disable is present: True
>
> Windows OS support for speculative store bypass disable is enabled system-wide: False

**Speculation control settings for CVE-2018-3620 [L1 terminal fault]**

> Hardware is vulnerable to L1 terminal fault: True
>
> Windows OS support for L1 terminal fault mitigation is present: True
>
> Windows OS support for L1 terminal fault mitigation is enabled: False

**Speculation control settings for MDS [microarchitectural data sampling]**

> Windows OS support for MDS mitigation is present: True
>
> Hardware is vulnerable to MDS: True
>
> Windows OS support for MDS mitigation is enabled: False

**Suggested actions**

> - Install BIOS/firmware update provided by your device OEM that enables hardware support for the branch target injection mitigation.
> - Follow the guidance for enabling Windows Server support for speculation control mitigations described in https://support.microsoft.com/help/4072698
>
> BTIHardwarePresent                  : False
>
> BTIWindowsSupportPresent            : True
>
> BTIWindowsSupportEnabled            : False
>
> BTIDisabledBySystemPolicy           : True
>
> BTIDisabledByNoHardwareSupport      : True
>
> BTIKernelRetpolineEnabled           : False
>
> BTIKernelImportOptimizationEnabled  : False
>
> KVAShadowRequired                   : True
>
> KVAShadowWindowsSupportPresent      : True
>
> KVAShadowWindowsSupportEnabled      : False
>
> KVAShadowPcidEnabled                : False
>
> SSBDWindowsSupportPresent           : True
>
> SSBDHardwareVulnerable              : True
>
> SSBDHardwarePresent                 : False
>
> SSBDWindowsSupportEnabledSystemWide : False
>
> L1TFHardwareVulnerable              : True
>
> L1TFWindowsSupportPresent           : True
>
> L1TFWindowsSupportEnabled           : False
>
> L1TFInvalidPteBit                   : 45
>
> L1DFlushSupported                   : False
>
> MDSWindowsSupportPresent            : True
>
> MDSHardwareVulnerable               : True
>
> MDSWindowsSupportEnabled            : False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could mean the registry values do not exist to enable the mitigation.

You can get more information by running the Microsoft Speculation Control script.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074629/understanding-the-output-of-get-speculationcontrolsettings-powershell

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4072698/windows-server-speculative-execution-side-channel-vulnerabilities-prot

The registry values will differ if Hyper-threading is enabled or disabled:

Enabled:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 72 /f

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverrideMask /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

Disabled:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 8264 /f

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverrideMask /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

A restart is required to go into effect.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that when I can restart the server. The only setting I have in the registry is `FeatureSettings=3`. Do you know if there are any known issues if I enable those options?

Comment: Two of the four vulnerability classes require firmware/microcode updates. Enabling the MDS settings implies enabling the settings for the other classes. The settings should not be enabled unless the firmware/microcode has been updated. This should be reported in the script output.

Comment: Added output. If I'm understanding it correctly, it's supported but not enabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: `BTIDisabledByNoHardwareSupport : True`. That's not a good sign. My guess is it is an old AMI (not sure what you are running). I wouldn't enable the setting, but maybe someone else that has done this can provide more information.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I guess I'll leave it like that then until I can update. Yes, the AMI is pretty old.

Comment: I've setup a brand new instance of Win Server 2016 and it still has `BTIDisabledByNoHardwareSupport: True`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DiegoJancic: what is the date of the BIOS/Firmware?

Comment: it's an freshly launched EC2 instance, so I don't know

Comment: @DiegoJancic: `systeminfo | findstr /C:BIOS`. Probably an old image that does not have support for the remediations.  Also note that paravirtualized instances cannot be remediated.  https://aws.amazon.com/speculative-execution-os-updates/

Comment: The instances are running on `HVM`. The command you shared, for a freshly launched instance, returns `Xen 4.2.amazon, 8/24/2006`

Comment: FYI, running all the scripts in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4072698/windows-server-speculative-execution-side-channel-vulnerabilities fixed the security vulnerabilities in Win Server 2016. Thanks for all your help.